# Is it safe to use GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument method

Tags: java, spring

I need to get class type from the generic interface in runtime. I wrote a code using GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument method:

```
public interface Example<D extends CommonDTO> {
    default void getFilter() {
        final Class<?> genericClass = GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), Example.class);
        ....
    }
}

public class ExampleIml implements Example<SomeDTO> {
    
}
```

One line is confusing me in the jdoc:

```
@return the resolved type of the argument, or {@code null} if not resolvable
```

Base on this line of the documentation i can presume that in some cases this method would not able to resolve type and return null. So my question
**Is it safe to use this method?**

I know that generic is erase for runtime, but info still available in the generic class metadata, so in theory, this use of this method should not be a problem.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by _safe_ and _not a problem_?

Comment: I edited my question. I just know that generics in runtime is not so simple subject, and worry, that this method in some cases for valid arguments can return null

Comment: It goes back to the rest of the javadoc: _which is assumed to implement the generic interface and possibly declare a concrete type for its type variable._ If the class doesn't implement the interface or doesn't have a type argument for the corresponding generic type, then the method will return `null`.